# onhover change image and text position down and onmouseout go to initial position?

Tags: html, css

May I know how to change image as well text inside image change its position?  When I hover image its moving down, but not the text.  The image is working properly, but not the text.

Fiddle:

```
h2 { 
   position:fixed; 
  margin-top:40px;
   left: 50; 

   z-index:100;
 height:100%;
}
h2:hover{
  position: relative; 
  margin-top:-50px;
   left: 50; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mjLLgce7/1/

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: check jsfidle here  https://jsfiddle.net/mjLLgce7/1/

Comment: If I understood correctly, try this:    a:hover h2{margin-top: 50px}

Comment: There are many things wrong with your script. On certain mouse positions, the image keeps going up and down on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Very buggy codes which would not have been possible without some major changes in css styling

**(I tried not to touch your script!)**

```css
h2 {
margin:0px;
  line-height:none;

}

  a{
  vertical-align:top;
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative; 
 }
 a:hover{
   top:50px;
 }
```

```html
<script>
function b1(x1) {
    x1.style.height = "140px";
    x1.style.width = "120px";
}

function s1(x2) {
    x2.style.height = "100px";
    x2.style.width = "120px";
}

function b2(x3) {
    x3.style.height = "140px";
    x3.style.width = "120px";
}

function s2(x4) {
    x4.style.height = "100px";
    x4.style.width = "120px";
}

function b3(x5) {
    x5.style.height = "140px";
    x5.style.width = "120px";
}

function s3(x6) {
    x6.style.height = "100px";
    x6.style.width = "120px";
}

function b4(x7) {
    x7.style.height = "140px";
    x7.style.width = "120px";
}

function s4(x8) {
    x8.style.height = "100px";
    x8.style.width = "120px";
}

function b5(x9) {
    x9.style.height = "140px";
    x9.style.width = "120px";
}

function s5(x) {
    x.style.height = "100px";
    x.style.width = "120px";
}

function b6(x12) {
    x12.style.height = "140px";
    x12.style.width = "120px";
}

function s6(x12) {
    x12.style.height = "100px";
    x12.style.width = "120px";
}
</script>


<a href="#">
  <h2>some text1</h2>
  <img onmouseover="b1(this)"  border="0" src="http://newshores.newshores.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/why-study.png" onmouseout="s1(this)" alt="study"/>
</a>

<a href="#" class>
  <h2>some text1</h2>
  <img onmouseover="b2(this)" onmouseout="s2(this)" border="0" src="http://newshores.newshores.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/graduate.png" alt="graduate"/>
</a>

<a href="#" class>
  <h2>some text1</h2>
  <img onmouseover="b3(this)" onmouseout="s3(this)" border="0" src="http://newshores.newshores.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/pg.png" alt="pg" />
</a>

<a href="#" class>
  <h2>some text1</h2>
  <img onmouseover="b4(this)" onmouseout="s4(this)" border="0" src="http://newshores.newshores.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/pre-university.png" alt="pre-uni"/>
</a>
```

Comment: http://www.regent-college.edu/   check this side top right menu i want similar type of hover action,this is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mjLLgce7/1/